# Android Terminal Emulator on AVD

Tags: android

I know that a few terminal emulators are available via the google app store

Is there a way of installing these apps on an AVD rather than an actual device?

I don't currently have a smartphone so all my development is currently via an emulator

Comment: For what do you need that? Are you aware that you can get a shell to your AVD by using [`adb shell`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands) on your dev-machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find one that distributes their apps outside of the Play Store, such as an open source project. Those should be eligible to install on an emulator.

Comment: do you know of such a terminal emulator? - all pretty new to me

Comment: @Hiett: I just use `adb shell` from my development machine to get at a shell on the emulator. I have never had the need to investigate anything more elaborate than that -- sorry!